# Integrate Tk grid widget into notebook layout

Tags: user-interface, tcl, prototype, tk-toolkit

I want to quickly prototype a GUI and thought that Tk could be simple to learn. However, I failed to integrate a sample grid view (frame) into one of the tabs of the notebook widget. The `pack` command places the grid on top of the notebook and I could not figure out the correct option. Or is my approach anyhow wrong?

Here is the code:

```
ttk::frame .c
ttk::frame .c.f -borderwidth 5 -relief sunken -width 200 -height 100
ttk::label .c.namelbl -text Name
ttk::entry .c.name
ttk::checkbutton .c.one -text One -variable one -onvalue 1; set one 1
ttk::checkbutton .c.two -text Two -variable two -onvalue 1; set two 0
ttk::checkbutton .c.three -text Three -variable three -onvalue 1; set three 1
ttk::button .c.ok -text Okay
ttk::button .c.cancel -text Cancel

grid .c -column 0 -row 0
grid .c.f -column 0 -row 0 -columnspan 3 -rowspan 2
grid .c.namelbl -column 3 -row 0 -columnspan 2
grid .c.name -column 3 -row 1 -columnspan 2
grid .c.one -column 0 -row 3
grid .c.two -column 1 -row 3
grid .c.three -column 2 -row 3
grid .c.ok -column 3 -row 3
grid .c.cancel -column 4 -row 3

# Notebook --> shall contain above grid in third tab
ttk::notebook .n  -width 600 -height 200
ttk::frame .n.f1; 
ttk::frame .n.f2; 
.n add .n.f1 -text "FirstTab"
.n add .n.f2 -text "SecondTab"
.n add .c -text "GridContent"
pack [label .n.f1.f1 -background red -foreground white -text "First"]
pack [label .n.f2.f2 -background red -foreground white -text "Second"]
pack .c 
pack .n 
ttk::notebook::enableTraversal .n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content widgets of a `ttk::notebook` *must* be higher in the stacking order than the notebook for it to work correctly, and *must* be managed by the notebook itself and not by `pack` or `grid` (though their contents can be managed any way you want); notebooks are a special kind of geometry manager as well as being a widget. (Tk has several other widgets that do this too.)

To fix the stacking order, either create the `.c` widget after the `.n` widget, or `raise .c` after creating `.n`. Note that a parent widget's children (except for `toplevel`s, and `menu`s in a few circumstances) always come on top of the parent, and are always bounded/clipped by their parent.

To fix the management issue, simply don't `pack .c`; adding it to the notebook is enough. You may pack or grid the contents of `.c` as you see fit.

---

With those two small fixes, your UI appears to work.

```
ttk::frame .c
ttk::frame .c.f -borderwidth 5 -relief sunken -width 200 -height 100
ttk::label .c.namelbl -text Name
ttk::entry .c.name
ttk::checkbutton .c.one -text One -variable one -onvalue 1; set one 1
ttk::checkbutton .c.two -text Two -variable two -onvalue 1; set two 0
ttk::checkbutton .c.three -text Three -variable three -onvalue 1; set three 1
ttk::button .c.ok -text Okay
ttk::button .c.cancel -text Cancel

grid .c -column 0 -row 0
grid .c.f -column 0 -row 0 -columnspan 3 -rowspan 2
grid .c.namelbl -column 3 -row 0 -columnspan 2
grid .c.name -column 3 -row 1 -columnspan 2
grid .c.one -column 0 -row 3
grid .c.two -column 1 -row 3
grid .c.three -column 2 -row 3
grid .c.ok -column 3 -row 3
grid .c.cancel -column 4 -row 3

# Notebook --> shall contain above grid in third tab
ttk::notebook .n  -width 600 -height 200
ttk::frame .n.f1; 
ttk::frame .n.f2; 
.n add .n.f1 -text "FirstTab"
.n add .n.f2 -text "SecondTab"
.n add .c -text "GridContent"
raise .c;   # <<<< YES! YOU DO WANT THIS! <<<< YES! <<<< YES! <<<< YES! <<<<
pack [label .n.f1.f1 -background red -foreground white -text "First"]
pack [label .n.f2.f2 -background red -foreground white -text "Second"]
# pack .c;  # <<<< NO! YOU DO NOT WANT THIS! <<<< NO! <<<< NO! <<<< NO! <<<<
pack .n 
ttk::notebook::enableTraversal .n
```